# Configure IIS Express to allow requests with public ip

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, port, iis-express

I just created a new ASP.NET Core API project which runs perfectly when I reach it like `localhost:50731` but when I do `83.11.58.141:50731` it's not reacheable.

I directed the router port to bridge the traffic and it works (tested with WireShark).

Some suggestions I saw where changing the `applicationhost.config` but that doesn't work for me.

This is what I have:

```
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50731:*" />
        </bindings>
```

I also tried without the last `*`, but same results.

Comment: Have you opened the corresponding port in your firewall ? Since you mentioned IIS Express, you should use Windows as OS. Windows has a firewall. If you don't allow access to this port through your firewall, then your request would never reach IIS. Read diagonally https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/sep/28/external-network-access-to-kestrel-and-iis-express-in-aspnet-core and I think that you might find here helpful advice about that.

Comment: @Christos Oh god, the freaking firewall. I thought that if it was reaching Wireshark for sure it was going throught the firewall.

Comment: If you found the cause, post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was allowing the port in the Windows Firewall.

> Windows Defender > Advanced configuration > Output rules > New rule